# find a solution from power series for multiple variable

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

$3^x4^y = 4,782,969 $ where $x$ and $y$ are integers. What is the value of $y$?
Is there any theory to solve this type problem?
i have tried to make  $4,782,969$ into power series but couldn't. So a formal example can be helpful for me to solve this.

Addition: 
if I ad $6^z$ then what would be the solution?

Comment: What"s in the other side of the equation?

Comment: Sorry just corrected

Comment: $4782969  =3^{14}\implies x=14, y=0$ as $(3,4)=1$

Comment: How did you make the scientific form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y$ has to be zero, because 4,782,969 is odd.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is called the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  It says that every integer greater than 1 can be factored uniquely as a product of prime numbers.  Factoring both sides of the equation into primes (using lab bhattacharjee's result) yields

$$2^{2y}3^x=2^03^{14}$$

As a result, we have $y=0$ and $x=14$ as the only integer solution.

Your other example

$$2^z3^z=2^03^{14}$$

has no solution as $z$ cannot be simultaneously equal to both $0$ and $14$.

Comment: How we got quickly $3^{14}$ from 4,782,969 ?

Comment: @ComplexGuy As I stated, I used lab bhattacharjee's comment.  On the other hand, for a solution to exist, since one side has only 2s and 3s as primes, the only way for a solution to exist is for the right hand side to only be divisible by 2s and 3s as well.  And as implied in Integral's answer, 4,782,969 is clearly not divisible by 2.